# React Native and Realm - Architecture

Tags: react-native, design-patterns, architecture, realm

So I'm building a React Native application where I'll need to have my data stored on the device offline, only syncing the data in the morning and evening.

The solution I've is Realm. My question is about the structure of the application. As far as I can tell using a Realm database removes the need to have a flux architecture manage my state as this is what Realm would be doing no?

I wanted to see what people are doing in terms of structure or design patterns. Would I implement some sort of ad-hoc mvc? Or mimic redux somehow?

I am asking about the app's possible design pattern but also about the physical folder structure. The app has the potential to be quite complex so I need to plan this thing out before I start.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This resource was pretty helpful for me in understanding how to mix Realm with Flux/Redux.

https://medium.com/@manggit/react-native-redux-realm-js-r3-js-a-new-mobile-development-standard-5290ec02a590

My opinion is that there are many other types of application state that can still be managed in Flux/Redux besides what might be persisted in Realm so I like this approach and it has been working for me so far.